# Can I define a time range for cookies, like JWT "nbf" and "exp"?

Tags: php, session-cookies, setcookie

I've seen that I can define a time range for a **JWT** with the `nbf`  and `exp` claim.

On a cookie I can define an expiration time. I read a lot today but is it possible that there is no way to define a start point in the future when the cookie should be **active**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie is a very small snippet of data (best practice being a nondescript identifying reference to data on the server).

You cannot use it like this as you do not know a future state of the server - unless you are amazing, in which case you do not need a cookie !!

So NO! redesign what you are doing :)